# Visual basic - Menu type statement

Tags: vb.net

I am in the process of starting a text-based game in Visual Basic in the console form and I want something that can be entered at any point. For example, at any point through the program, if the player types "menu", they open the menu options and clear the current console. I'm not sure how you can set something to be asked at any point through the program. I don't know if I have explained this well enough just say if I am not being clear, and I would really appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a list of your keywords that can be entered. You also save a string that starts out as empty. If the user presses a key you add this letter to the string. You then check all the words in your list for equality to your string. If a word matches, you reset the string to empty and do whatever command you want for the typed word. If the string is part of the beginning of a word you do nothing. If the string is part of none of the words you reset the string to empty.

You just have to make sure that a long word never starts with a short word that is also in your list. E.g. if you have for example an "equip" command that let's you equip a new item and an "equipment" command that shows your inventory, this would not work.

```
Module Module1
Private Delegate Sub deleDoSomething()
Private Sub HandleMenu()
    Console.WriteLine("MENU")
End Sub
Private Sub HandleWalk()
    Console.WriteLine("WALKING")
End Sub
Private Sub HandleExit()
    End
End Sub

Sub Main()
     Dim words As New Dictionary(Of String, deleDoSomething)
    words.Add("menu", AddressOf HandleMenu)
    words.Add("walk", AddressOf HandleWalk)
    words.Add("exit", AddressOf HandleExit)
    Dim currs As String = ""
    Do
        While Console.KeyAvailable = False
        End While
        Dim bla As ConsoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey(True)
        currs &= bla.KeyChar
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        For Each s As String In words.Keys
            If s = currs Then
                words(s)()
                currs = ""
            ElseIf currs.Length < s.Length Then
                If Strings.Left(s, currs.Length) = currs Then found = True
            End If
        Next
        If found = False Then currs = ""
    Loop
End Sub
End Module
```

I implemented the wordlist as a Dictionary(Of String, Delegate) so I can just call the appropriate Sub by calling `words(s)()`. The rest is as I wrote above.